# Python Flask app failed to connect to redshift database

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

My simple python flask application failed to connect to redshift database. Logged error :

> psycopg2.OperationalError: could not create SSL context: library has
>   no ciphers FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::ffff:0.0.0.0",
>   user "admin", database "redshiftdb", SSL off

But when I the try same connection works well with simple python(simple.py) without flask.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="redshiftdb", user = "admin", password = "admin!pwd", host = "remotehost", port = "5439")

print ("Opened database successfully")
```

but with flask it does not work (**init**.py).

```
from flask import Flask
import psycopg2

@app.route("/service")
def service():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="redshiftdb", user = "admin", password = "admin!pwd", host = "remotehost", port = "5439")
    return "Service is running!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

- ubuntu v12
- Python version : 3.4
- psycopg2==2.7.5
- psycopg2-binary==2.7.5
- Flask==1.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally following installations fixed the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install  libpq-dev python-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-psycopg2
```

After this installation, I reinstalled psycopg2

```
pip3 install psycopg2
```

I don't know theory behind this fix, why and how it works.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest *psycopg2* also fixes this issue for me: `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall psycopg2`

Answer (score 2):

Try to build psycopg2 from source

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Inlcude in requirements.txt

```
psycopg2==2.7.5 --no-binary :all:
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and sorry for late response, I tried this, but not working. I noticed one more thing, it is not just about psycopg2 package, Flask application not recognizing any new package installed. I restarted apache2 , still no luck :(